# Toggle boolean value in Boolean prototype

Tags: javascript, boolean

I'm trying to create a toggle method for booleans, and I can't figure out how to set the boolean value, here is my code:

```
var booleanMethod = Boolean.prototype

booleanMethod.toggle = function() {
    //something like this.value = !this.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't.

When inside the prototype, `this` refers to the current instance of the object, in this case a `Boolean`. You can't modify `this` - it's a *value*. You can't assign a value to a value, only a reference to a value.

```
this = !this;
```

Is like saying `true = false` which makes no sense whatsoever.

Moreover, you can't *change an instance itself in a method of the instance*. Sure you can change properties of an instance with setters, but you can't change the instance. That's breaks the design pattern, you can't just reassign an instance to something else inside *an instance method*. Say we have an apple. You can't just turn the apple into an orange or another apple.

Lastly, what's wrong with negating the value outside? You can't change an instance inside a method *of that instance*, but you can reassign a reference to that instance.

Going back to the apple and orange example, imagine you're now holding the apple in your hand. You can't change the apple itself, it's always going to be that specific apple, but you can change which fruit you have in your hand, the hand being a reference and the fruit being an instance.

In this case, you can just negate it outside an instance method:

```
let x = false; //or Boolean(false)
x = !x;
```

There's nothing wrong with using the NOT operator.